# R: Export 3D scatterplots non-interactively

Tags: r, plot, rgl

Creating 3D plots in R opens up an interactive window where the user can rotate the view. For example below using package `rgl`:

```
library(rgl)
plot3d(iris[,1:3],col=c("red","green","blue")[iris$Species],size=5)
```

[image]

Is there some way to set a predefined view and export the plot as a regular image. I would like to do this in an automated non-interactive manner for many datasets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `scatterplot3d` package.

```
library(scatterplot3d)
graphics.off()
png(filename = "test.png", width = 8, height = 6, units = "in", res = 300)
par(mai = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
scatterplot3d(x = iris$Sepal.Length, y = iris$Sepal.Width, z = iris$Petal.Length,
              color = c("red","green","blue")[iris$Species],
              cex.symbols = 1, pch = 19, angle = -30)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Besides @d.b's answer using `scatterplot3d` instead of `rgl`, you could save results using R Markdown.  The advantage of doing it this way is that you get an interactive display instead of a static one; the disadvantage is that the format is HTML, not PNG or another bitmap format.

Before knitting the document, run code like this and interactively choose
the initial display you want:

```
library(rgl)
options(rgl.useNULL = FALSE)
plot3d(iris[,1:3],col=c("red","green","blue")[iris$Species],size=5)
```

Once you have it oriented correctly, run this code:

```
M <- par3d("userMatrix")
dput(M)
```

You'll get something like

```
structure(c(0.776694416999817, 0.198224693536758, -0.597873568534851, 
0, -0.629868388175964, 0.249577552080154, -0.735511302947998, 
0, 0.00341932475566864, 0.947849154472351, 0.318700969219208, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))
```

as output.  Then start your R Markdown document with something like

```
library(rgl)
options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)
M <- structure(c(0.776694416999817, 0.198224693536758, -0.597873568534851, 
0, -0.629868388175964, 0.249577552080154, -0.735511302947998, 
0, 0.00341932475566864, 0.947849154472351, 0.318700969219208, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))
```

(which you would probably choose not to echo), and in each code chunk that produces a plot, write code like this:

```
plot3d(iris[,1:3],col=c("red","green","blue")[iris$Species],size=5)
par3d(userMatrix = M)
rglwidget()
```

(If this is in a loop or isn't at the top level for some other reason, you'll need `print(rglwidget())` instead.)

Then all of your plots will initially have the same orientation, but all of them will be user-rotatable.

Comment: This is neat. Is it possible to add a legend?

Comment: Not like the one in ggplot(), but you can add one as a background image.  Be careful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562604/rgl-low-resolution-legend shows some of the things that can go wrong.